# How to add module dependency to other module in Java Project Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, module, jar

I havr two modules in this project (JavaRESTfulEngine and Models). Java RESTful engine depends on models. [image]

I added the dependency here:
[image]

But in my JavaRESTfulEngine project I still get reference errors. For example, the Document class is in the Models module, but I cannot find it when trying to import the class in JavaRESTful module:
[image]
The goal is that Models is compiled down to a jar and used in the JavaRESTful project during runtime. Does anything stand out as wrong in my setup?
**EDIT**
I changed the scope from compile to provided and it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to change the scope of the jars. If you want to use the libraries of the **Models** module in the **JavaRESTfulEngine** module, you just have to make sure that each jar you want to reuse from **Models** has the "Export" check box activated and that the reference to the **Models** folder is inside the **JavaRESTfulEngine** module (just like I see you have it in the second photo)